# What is the correct way to add a Service Group (Virtual Service) on SoftLayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to create an Auto Scale Group.  This new Auto Scale Group will need to point to a new (Service Group, Service Port) entry on an existing Local Load Balancer Virtual IP address.

From the website, I can select "Add Group" and enter (GroupType, Method, Virtual Port, Allocation) which seem to be fields on a SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualServer 
(there also seems to be a type called SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Service_Group but it doesn't have the correct field names).

I tried using the following POST web request to create a new VirtualServer (Service Group?) on an existing Local Load Balancer and it returns a 404 error code.

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualServer.json

```
{
  "parameters": 
  [
    {
      "allocation": 12,
      "port": 1290,
      "routingMethodId": null,
      "virtualIpAddressId": 157345
    }
  ]
}
```

=== EDITED ===

Following your advice, I tried the following:

GET

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/157345/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[virtualServers[serviceGroups]]

RESPONSE

```
{
   "accountId": 940999,
   "connectionLimit": 250,
   "connectionLimitUnits": "connections\/second",
   "dedicatedFlag": false,
   "id": 157345,
   "ipAddressId": 11112844,
   "notes": "CaffeLoadBalancer",
   "securityCertificateId": null,
   "sslActiveFlag": false,
   "sslEnabledFlag": false,
   "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
   "managedResourceFlag": false,
   "virtualServers": [{
      "allocation": 12,
      "id": 274353,
      "port": 1201,
      "routingMethodId": null,
      "virtualIpAddressId": 157345,
      "serviceGroups": [{
         "id": 270313,
         "routingMethodId": 3,
         "routingTypeId": 3,
         "timeout": null
      }],
      "virtualIpAddress": {
         "accountId": 940999,
         "connectionLimit": 250,
         "connectionLimitUnits": "connections\/second",
         "dedicatedFlag": false,
         "id": 157345,
         "ipAddressId": 11112844,
         "notes": "CaffeLoadBalancer",
         "securityCertificateId": null,
         "sslActiveFlag": false,
         "sslEnabledFlag": false,
         "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
         "managedResourceFlag": false,
         "virtualServers": null
      }
   }]
}
```

I then modified the response to this:

```
{
"parameters": 
[

 {
  "accountId": 940999,
  "connectionLimit": 250,
  "connectionLimitUnits": "connections\/second",
  "dedicatedFlag": false,
  "id": 157345,
  "ipAddressId": 11112844,
  "notes": "CaffeLoadBalancer",
  "securityCertificateId": null,
  "sslActiveFlag": false,
  "sslEnabledFlag": false,
  "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
  "managedResourceFlag": false,
  "virtualServers": 
   [
   {
    "allocation": 12,
    "id": 274353,
    "port": 1201,
    "routingMethodId": null,
    "virtualIpAddressId": 157345,
    "serviceGroups": [{
      "id": 270313,
      "routingMethodId": 3,
      "routingTypeId": 3,
      "timeout": null
    }],
    "virtualIpAddress": {
      "accountId": 940999,
      "connectionLimit": 250,
      "connectionLimitUnits": "connections\/second",
      "dedicatedFlag": false,
      "id": 157345,
      "ipAddressId": 11112844,
      "notes": "CaffeLoadBalancer",
      "securityCertificateId": null,
      "sslActiveFlag": false,
      "sslEnabledFlag": false,
      "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
      "managedResourceFlag": false,
      "virtualServers": null
    }
  },
   {
    "allocation": 12,
    "port": 1290,
    "routingMethodId": null,
    "virtualIpAddressId": 157345,
    "serviceGroups": [{
      "id": 270313,
      "routingMethodId": 3,
      "routingTypeId": 3,
      "timeout": null
    }],
    "virtualIpAddress": {
      "accountId": 940999,
      "connectionLimit": 250,
      "connectionLimitUnits": "connections\/second",
      "dedicatedFlag": false,
      "id": 157345,
      "ipAddressId": 11112844,
      "notes": "CaffeLoadBalancer",
      "securityCertificateId": null,
      "sslActiveFlag": false,
      "sslEnabledFlag": false,
      "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
      "managedResourceFlag": false,
      "virtualServers": null
    }
  }
  ]
}

]
}
```

and POSTed it to:

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/157345/editObject.json

and I get the the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: Try removing all the IDs of the added virtualServer, as the virtual server does not exist all ids need to created.

Comment: I updated my answer, see the last virtual server added you do not need to set all values

Comment: I tested removing the ServiceGroup Id (specifically the second ["id": 270313] and that made it succeed.  It was kind of disappointing though that the newly generated Id wasn't returned at all (all I got was "true").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so easy you need to edit the load balnacer calling the method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/e

basically you need to edit the configuration of the virtualServer contained in the load balancer by adding a new [virtual server object](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress)

The Request will look to something like this:

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/$LOADBALANCERID/editObject
    {
    "parameters": [{
        "connectionLimit": 500,
        "connectionLimitUnits": "connections/second",
        "dedicatedFlag": false,
        "id": 79945,
        "ipAddressId": 25132124,
        "notes": "This is for test",
        "sslActiveFlag": false,
        "sslEnabledFlag": false,
        "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
        "managedResourceFlag": false,
        "virtualServers": [{
            "allocation": 40,
            "id": 192913,
            "port": 70,
            "virtualIpAddressId": 79945,
            "serviceGroups": [{
                "id": 188753,
                "notes": "group 2",
                "routingMethodId": 11,
                "routingTypeId": 3
            }],
            "virtualIpAddress": {
                "connectionLimit": 500,
                "connectionLimitUnits": "connections/second",
                "dedicatedFlag": false,
                "id": 79945,
                "ipAddressId": 25132124,
                "notes": "This is for test",
                "sslActiveFlag": false,
                "sslEnabledFlag": false,
                "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
                "managedResourceFlag": false
            }
        }, {
            "allocation": 10,
            "id": 140553,
            "port": 80,
            "virtualIpAddressId": 79945,
            "serviceGroups": [{
                "id": 138193,
                "notes": "group note 2",
                "routingMethodId": 2,
                "routingTypeId": 2
            }],
            "virtualIpAddress": {
                "connectionLimit": 500,
                "connectionLimitUnits": "connections/second",
                "dedicatedFlag": false,
                "id": 79945,
                "ipAddressId": 25132124,
                "notes": "This is for test",
                "sslActiveFlag": false,
                "sslEnabledFlag": false,
                "highAvailabilityFlag": false,
                "managedResourceFlag": false
            }
        },{
            "port": 81,
            "allocation": 10,
            "serviceGroups": [{
                "notes": "group note 2",
                "routingMethodId": 2,
                "routingTypeId": 2
            }]
        }]
    }]

}
```

I suggest you first to get the configuration of the load balancer using the request bellow, then add the new Virtual server object and call the edit object method:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/$LOADBALANCERID/getObject?objectMask=mask[virtualServers[serviceGroups]]
```

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect your suggested changes.